# constexpr linked list - invalid conversion from const X* to X*

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++14, constexpr, c++17

Here's my attempt at creating a simple constexpr linked list -

```
struct Node
{
    constexpr Node(const int n, Node const* next = nullptr)
        : value(n), next(next) {}
    constexpr Node push(const int n) const { return Node(n, this); }

    int value;
    Node const* next;
};

constexpr auto getSum(Node n) {
    int sum = 0;
    Node *current = &n;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        sum += current->value;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    constexpr Node a(0);
    a.push(1);
    a.push(22);
    constexpr auto result = getSum(a);
    return result;
}
```

on compiling this program, the following error is shown

```
prog.cc: In function 'constexpr auto getSum(Node)':
prog.cc:16:28: error: invalid conversion from 'const Node*' to 'Node*' [-fpermissive]
         current = current->next;
                   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:25:35:   in constexpr expansion of 'getSum(a)'
prog.cc:16:28: error: conversion of 'const Node*' null pointer to 'Node*' is not a constant expression
```

---

How should I proceed forward to solve this issue and generate such linked list? Here is [**Wandbox Link**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s85qz0VxZfZQcT2c) for seeing the execution online.

Comment: wow, I don't thinks its possible what you're doing...

Comment: `constexpr` objects still follow the rules of the abstract machine. All the calls to `push` return a temporary that immediately expires. Your list will never grow, even if you fix the error.

Comment: Damn.. that has to be the most `const` and `constexpr` I have ever seen..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate error is straightforward to fix:

```
  Node const *current = &n;
  //   ^^^^^
```

The complaint is that `current = current->next;` is assigning a `Node const*` to a `Node *`, so don't do that.

Doing that will make your program compile but print `0`, because neither `push` calls modified `a`. You also can't store the result of `push` as `constexpr` since the address of `a`, an automatic local variable, isn't a constant expression.

You can, however, form a linked list of temporary nodes and immediately use it:

```
constexpr auto result = getSum(a.push(1).push(22).push(19)); // OK, 42
```

Answer (score 1):

As @hg_git pointed out in the commentary of your post, a `constexpr` linked list is not possible.

I cleaned up your code to have a useful error.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    constexpr Node(const int n, Node * next = nullptr)
        : value(n), next(next) {}
    constexpr Node push(const int n) { return Node(n, this); }

    int value;
    Node * next;
};

constexpr auto getSum(Node n) {
    int sum = 0;
    Node *current = &n;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        sum += current->value;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    constexpr Node a(0);
    a.push(1);
    a.push(22);
    constexpr auto result = getSum(a);
    return result;
}
```

Giving this

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:13: error: passing 'const Node' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     a.push(1);
             ^
main.cpp:7:20: note:   in call to 'constexpr Node Node::push(int)'
     constexpr Node push(const int n) { return Node(n, this); }
                    ^~~~
main.cpp:26:14: error: passing 'const Node' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     a.push(22);
              ^
main.cpp:7:20: note:   in call to 'constexpr Node Node::push(int)'
     constexpr Node push(const int n) { return Node(n, this); }
```

As you can see, even if the keyword `const` is not there, there is still some problems with const parameters. This comes from the fact that constexpr are calculated at compilation time. Thus making them immutable at run time.

A linked list could change at runtime; if you add or remove a Node per example. 
So `constexpr` are not the right choice in this case.

Edit :
Here's a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7157982047a41f89) of your code, clean from `constexpr`. I added some commentary, feel free to ask if you don't understand a line or a function.

Comment: it is possible, we just need to take care of lifetimes of temporary objects :)